# Node.js Need a better understanding of http.request action(s) when no server is available to handle request

Tags: javascript, node.js

From the Nodejs.v8.11.3 API doc I am trying to get a better understanding of the behavior of `http.request` (form the embedded http module). It is my understanding that when you invoke `http.request` method as shown below:

```
var req = http.request( options, function(res) {
   res.on('data',function(chunk) {...});
   res.on('end',function() {...});
});

req.end();
req.setTimeout(2*60*1000, function() { 
   req.abort(); 
}
```

that `http.request` returns `http.ClientRequest` object and the `callback` provides the means of setting up handlers to address the response. The returned `ClientRequest` object represents a 'queued' request and the actual request is not sent until one invokes the `req.end()` method.

Additionally one can define a connection timeout which I believes emits when a connection has been established and the underlying socket AND the socket has been inactive for the specified milliseconds.

My question is what happens if there is no server to respond to the request? Will `request.end()` trigger some event or error condition if no server is available?

From what I am seeing is that the timeout event is never emitted because no connection has been established.

What is the correct behavior for the calling code when no server is available to handle the request? The request is queued and will eventually be handled when a server comes on-line. Is that correct?

What should the calling code do while it waits for server to respond? The calls are non-blocking and if your primary task is to read/process data from the issued `http.request` what should your code do while waiting to the server to respond?  Does one use a `setInterval` in a loop?  What am I missing?

Any help to gain a deeper understanding to how to structure the code to address this situation would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what happens if there is no server to respond to the request?

See the documentation:

> In the case of a connection error, the following events will be
>   emitted:
>
> - 'socket'
> - 'error'
> - 'close'

---

> The request is queued and will eventually be handled when a server comes on-line. Is that correct?

No. The connection attempt will be refused because there is no server listening. There is no automatic retry.

Comment: Thanks for some clarification.  However I have been reviewing the documentation. For clarification, if there is no server available is it considered a 'connection error'? i.e., receive a socket, error, and close events?